# Read an already existing (pre-made) textfile?

Tags: java, android

I couldnt really find an answer to how to read an existing textfile (.txt for example) into my Application.
Basicly I want to give the App a textfile on its way to my phone when I install it, my question is where I have to put the file in my source folder for it to properly work.

I've read somewhere that I have to put it in a folder called "raw", but I cant find anything. Do I need to create it?
Im working with Android Studio if thats somehow important.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Do I need to create it?` Yes, if not already existing. Or use the `assets` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make a directory called `raw` under `res`
Put your textfile there.
E.g
`res/raw/textfile.txt`

You can now acquire an `InputStream` to this file

```
InputStream intputStream = this.getContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textfile);
```